# include sub-view in master page and clear my data after login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

When i using `@include` in master page blade template for add header and sidebar page,this action makes clear login data.
i've tried.without using include in master page below code printing login data

```
{{Auth::User()->first_name . ' ' . Auth::User()->family}}
```

but after add include,with one refresh page all login data is cleared!

master page:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('asset/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('asset/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('asset/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('asset/css/style.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('asset/css/style-responsive.css')}}">
    <script  src="{{URL::asset('asset/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    @yield('css')

</head>
<body>
{{--Header Start--}}
@include('layouts.header')
{{--End Header--}}

{{--Sidebar Start--}}
@include('layouts.sidebar')
{{--End Sidebar--}}

{{--Content Start--}}
@yield('content')
{{--End Content--}}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('asset/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('asset/js/jquery.nicescroll.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('asset/js/common-scripts.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('asset/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js')}}"></script>
@yield('js')
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

call view:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

and this is my header page:

```
<section id="container" class="">
    <!--header start-->
    <header class="header white-bg">
        <div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
            <div data-original-title="Toggle Navigation" data-placement="right" class="fa fa-reorder tooltips"></div>
        </div>
        <!--logo start-->
        <a href="#" class="logo">PTA<span>OIMS</span></a>
        <!--logo end-->
        <div class="nav notify-row" id="top_menu">
            <!--  notification start -->
            <ul class="nav top-menu">
                <!-- settings start -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
                        <span class="badge bg-success">6</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu extended tasks-bar">
                        <div class="notify-arrow notify-arrow-green"></div>
                        <li>
                            <p class="green">You have 6 pending tasks</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="task-info">
                                    <div class="desc">Dashboard v1.3</div>
                                    <div class="percent">40%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="task-info">
                                    <div class="desc">Database Update</div>
                                    <div class="percent">60%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="task-info">
                                    <div class="desc">Iphone Development</div>
                                    <div class="percent">87%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 87%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">87% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="task-info">
                                    <div class="desc">Mobile App</div>
                                    <div class="percent">33%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 33%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">33% Complete (danger)</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="task-info">
                                    <div class="desc">Dashboard v1.3</div>
                                    <div class="percent">45%</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                    <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                                        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="external">
                            <a href="#">See All Tasks</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- settings end -->
                <!-- inbox dropdown start-->
                <li id="header_inbox_bar" class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <span class="badge bg-important">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu extended inbox">
                        <div class="notify-arrow notify-arrow-red"></div>
                        <li>
                            <p class="red">You have 5 new messages</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="photo"><img alt="avatar" src="img/avatar-mini.jpg"></span>
                                    <span class="subject">
                                    <span class="from">Jonathan Smith</span>
                                    <span class="time">Just now</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="message">
                                        Hello, this is an example msg.
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="photo"><img alt="avatar" src="img/avatar-mini2.jpg"></span>
                                    <span class="subject">
                                    <span class="from">Jhon Doe</span>
                                    <span class="time">10 mins</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="message">
                                     Hi, Jhon Doe Bhai how are you ?
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="photo"><img alt="avatar" src="img/avatar-mini3.jpg"></span>
                                    <span class="subject">
                                    <span class="from">Jason Stathum</span>
                                    <span class="time">3 hrs</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="message">
                                        This is awesome dashboard.
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="photo"><img alt="avatar" src="img/avatar-mini4.jpg"></span>
                                    <span class="subject">
                                    <span class="from">Jondi Rose</span>
                                    <span class="time">Just now</span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="message">
                                        Hello, this is metrolab
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">See all messages</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- inbox dropdown end -->
                <!-- notification dropdown start-->
                <li id="header_notification_bar" class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">

                        <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                        <span class="badge bg-warning">7</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu extended notification">
                        <div class="notify-arrow notify-arrow-yellow"></div>
                        <li>
                            <p class="yellow">You have 7 new notifications</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></span>
                                Server #3 overloaded.
                                <span class="small italic">34 mins</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                Server #10 not respoding.
                                <span class="small italic">1 Hours</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></span>
                                Database overloaded 24%.
                                <span class="small italic">4 hrs</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                                New user registered.
                                <span class="small italic">Just now</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-bank"></i></span>
                                Application error.
                                <span class="small italic">10 mins</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">See all notifications</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- notification dropdown end -->
            </ul>
            <!--  notification end -->
        </div>
        <div class="top-nav ">
            <!--search & user info start-->
            <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
                <li>
                    <input class="form-control search fa fa-bell-o" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                </li>
                <!-- user login dropdown start-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <img alt="" src="img/avatar1_small.jpg">
                        <span class="username">
                            @if(Auth::check())
                            {{
                                Auth::User()->first_name . ' ' .
                                Auth::User()->family
                            }}</span>
                            @endif
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu extended logout">
                        <div class="log-arrow-up"></div>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class=" fa fa-suitcase"></i>Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i> Notification</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{Auth::logout()}}"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- user login dropdown end -->
            </ul>
            <!--search & user info end-->
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--header end-->
```

Comment: show us your header blade. as far as i know, `@include` has nothing to do with session

Comment: Have you set your browser to clear sessions on refresh etc?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem

in header and sidebar blade, i used this:

```
<li><a href="{{Auth::logout()}}"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

and changed with this code in below:

```
 <li><a href="logout"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>Logout</a></li>
```

and create route:

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```